# React js -compiled with errors

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Suddenly i got a compilation error after moving js files but i undo it it still
Here is my index.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="roOt"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And Here is my Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from "./componment/App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

and here is the fail img

[image]

I would be thankfull if you give me a hint .

hint or sloution of react

Comment: Typo?  `ID`s are canse-sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change id="ro**O**t" to id="ro**o**t"

Answer (score 0):

getElementById is case sensitive so in this case you don't have a div with an id called "root" and instead you have an id called "roOt". According to [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) getElementById in the docs:

> Parameters
> The ID is a case-sensitive string which is unique within the document; only one
> element should have any given ID.

Change your id to be "root" and you'll solve the problem

Comment: oh i didnt see !!!